# Java Spring POST API json input

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Developing a java spring based API for the first time. These APIs will be POST and would take JSON as input. I must not be connecting all of the dots because there is an error message when I invoke the api call from my rest client.

pom.xml

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Object to serialize from json

```
public class PostCountry {
    private String country;


    public void setCountry(String country){
        this.country=country;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCountries", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String getCountries(PostCountry country) {
        System.out.println(country.getCountry());
        MapDAOImpl mapDAOImpl = (MapDAOImpl) appContext.getBean("mapDAOImpl");
        System.out.println(mapDAOImpl.getCountries(country.getCountry()));
        return "";

    }
```

Error message thrown in rest client

```
<u>The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.</u>
```

[image: Rest call]

error

```
System.out.println(country.getCountry()); is null
```

Comment: What is the http call? Can you share some details?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I didn't realize you could attach pictures directly in here.

Comment: Spring should already depend to Jackson library, so Maven should download it even if you don't specify in pom.xml, can you try in that way?

Comment: Do you need to add `consumes="application/json"` to your `@RequestMapping` annotation?

Comment: You should add your Spring configuration. And what Spring version are you using?

Comment: The version of Jackson is outdated use Jackson 2 instead.
If you have Spring >3.1. Your config should extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` This class will detect if you have Jackson2 in your dependencies.

Comment: I only saw 1.9 as latest version. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl

Comment: They change groupId : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core

Comment: Updated the code. I seem to be getting a 404 error

Comment: Do not use `headers="Accept=application/json"`. Use `consumes` and `produces` parameters of `RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: hmm. still throws an error. "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.</"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was 2 fold. I needed to define some RequestMappingHandlerAdapter in the xml files.

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And define an empty constructor in the model

```
public class PostCountry {


    public String country;

    public PostCountry() {}

    public PostCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country){
        this.country=country;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

}




@RequestMapping(value = "/getCountries"                                    
        , method = RequestMethod.POST                                      
        , consumes = "application/json"                                    
        , produces = "application/json")                                   
@ResponseBody                                                              
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)                                
public ReturnCountries getCountries(@RequestBody PostCountry country) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding @RequestBody annotation to the parameter may be enough.

Comment: It wouldnt allow me to convert the json into a java object without what I mentioned above.